# What should connect to the COM contact on my new thermostat?

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat

I am replacing a fan-coil thermostat. Unit itself is Wito ultra-s 06-2t. Old one was wired and installed by an electrician, quite some time ago. I dismounted the old one and wanted to replace it with the new one, but it appears that there is a "COM" contact on a new one and nothing similar on the old. I'm quite inexperienced in wiring so I'd like to find out:

1. Whether wiring a COM is required for the thermostat/some of its features to work
2. Whether ignoring COM contact is safe
3. Whether there is any wire in the current setup (probably, one of the blue ones in the N slot) that should go into the COM contact

Old:
[image: old]

New:
[image: new]

Comment: I'm guessing that one of the blue wires that are doubled up is a COM (constant 24v) supply. Have you checked that? If so, that would move over.

Comment: I don't have an indicator screw, guess i need to get myself one to check that.

Comment: A _what_ now? I recommend any homeowner purchase an inexpensive multimeter.

Comment: Or that, yes, thank you for you input! At least i have faith that it'll work now!

Comment: this unit does not have 24 volt

Comment: @knowitall so there is no way to wire this thermostat? Unit model is Wito ultra-s 06-2t

Comment: It is not a thermostat is a relay control. Your thermostat is somewhere else. 1 and 7 are same. 8 is always hot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Jumper N to COM

From the wiring diagram on your new unit, it shows the COM terminal connected to the incoming mains neutral, so you should simply connect suitably sized wires from COM and N on the new thermostat to the mains neutral connection coming into your box with a suitable wire connector for your location.

Comment: So you are suggesting to change the wiring on the fan-coil unit? Or am I interpreting your answer wrong?

Comment: @HardLuck -- no, the jumpering I'm talking about takes place at the thermostat

Comment: I've tested blue wires with a multimeter, they are both zeros. To be perfectly clear on the course of action I: 1) jumper 1 and 7 2) wire 2:yellow, 3:green, 4:black, 5:nothing, 6:brown, 7:2x blue, 8:red. Is this correct?

Comment: @HardLuck -- if the terminals on the device are rated to accept two wires, then your plan is fine

Comment: any way i can verify that? Nothing about that in the user manual.

Comment: @HardLuck -- I'd presume it doesn't support 2 wires on the same terminal, then, and then connect pigtails from 1 and 7 on the thermostat to your neutral wire from the wall